# The return type of mxIsDouble, mxIsSingle, and mxIsClass (MATLAB mex for Fortran)

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, matlab-deployment

According to https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisclass.html
the return of mxIsDouble for Fortran (also mxIsSingle and mxIsClass) is INTEGER*4.

Here are my questions:

1. Should the declaration of mxIsDouble be always

   INTEGER*4 :: mxIsDouble  ?

What if I declare it as

```
INTEGER :: mxIsDouble
```

or

```
LOGICAL :: mxIsDouble ?
```

2. It is said that **INTEGER*4 is not standard and should be replaced by kind**. How should I do it? I know that **INTEGER(KIND=4) is incorrect**. In addition, why does mex continue to use such a **nonstandard** feature?

Background: I got these questions when writing a MATLAB interface for some Fortran legacy code. I am working on a 64 bit PC with Linux, yet I am aiming at writing **portable** mex files.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `INTEGER*4` was never a part of the Fortran standard, so how can it be obsolescent?  You'll need to ask Mathworks why it continues to use nonstandard syntax.  Just use `INTEGER` as this declaration corresponds to default integer kind.

Comment: Your best bet, after complaining to Mathsworks about their broken interface and documentation, might be to look at the constants int32, real32 and real64 in the standard module iso_fortran_env

Comment: Thank you @evets. I have edited the question and replaces "obsolete" by "nonstandard". If I use INTEGER to declare these functions, would everything work properly despite the fact that the default integer on my computer is 64 bit while the functions return 32-bit integers? Thank you very much!

Comment: What computer and operating system are you using?  The size of the default `INTEGER` is the same as the size of the default `REAL`, which in all likelihood is 32 bits.  You can output the size in bits with the `STORAGE_SIZE` intrinsic function.

Comment: Thank you @Steve. I am working on a Linux PC with 64bit MATLAB. In recent releases of MATLAB (e.g., MATLABR2018a), it seems that we do not necessarily have "the default INTEGER is the same as the size of the default REAL". On my computer, when complied with option -largeArrayDims, the default INTEGER is 64bit while the default REAL is 32bit. STORAGE_SIZE sounds very useful, yet it is available only after Fortran 2008. Do we have some function like that in Fortran90? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please define "portable". As I said in my comment to your other question, MEX-files are quite limited to which OSes and compilers you can use. "Portable" to me means supporting all of that limited set. It just gets difficult when you define "portable" as simultaneously compilable with the newest versions of MATLAB as well as some very old versions of MATLAB. Regarding `INTEGER*4`, if that is how it is declared by MATLAB, then that is how you should write it in your MEX-files to remain compatible. C MEX API uses `mwSize` and `mwIndex` for all integer input and output arguments.

Comment: Oh, the [Fortran API does too](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetnumberofdimensions.html), I guess Fortran doesn't have a boolean type, so they use a 4-byte integer? Just follow the official documentation for types, that will work with all supported compilers.

Comment: Fortran does have a boolean type, though it calls it `logical`.  And, a default `logical` variable has the same size as a default `integer`, generally 32b on most current compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use INTEGER*4 because that is what matches the MATLAB API doc, regardless of it being non-standard.  Don't use INTEGER because that might compile to a 64-bit integer depending on your settings and won't match the library function. Remember, you are linking to an already compiled library function that returns a 32-bit integer ... you are not recompiling the mxIsDouble function. E.g.,

```
INTEGER*4, external :: mxIsDouble
```

I think it highly unlikely MATLAB will ever change these functions to return anything other than a 32-bit integer, but I suppose you could create your own type for this so that the INTEGER*4 only appears at one place in your code.